# trying to get the asp.net equivalent for php sha1(md5($Password));

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I'm trying to get the php **sha1(md5($Password));**  like this

```
        public static string GetSha1MD5Pass(string value)
        {

            var data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
            var datamd5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(data);
            var data64 = Convert.ToBase64String(datamd5);
            var data64e = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data64);
            var hashData = new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(data64e);
            var hash = string.Empty;
            foreach (var b in hashData)
            {
                hash += b.ToString("X2");
            }
            return hash;

        }
```

I call it like this :

```
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", Crypto.GetSha1MD5Pass(password));
```

where Crypto its class I made were GetSha1MD5Pass resides

but it clearly failed, maybe someone here can help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is not recommended for secure hashing. It's considered a [deprecated algorithm](https://owasp.org/Top10/A02_2021-Cryptographic_Failures/) because it is relatively easy to break. The current recommendation is to use [PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 with 310,000 iterations](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html).

You can achieve this relatively easy in ASP.NET Core using the `PasswordHasher` helper in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` package. It has `HashPassword` and a `VerifyHashedPassword` methods. By default, the number of iterations is set to 10,000, but you can reconfigure that yourself:

```
builder.Services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options =>
{
    options.IterationCount = 310000;
});
```

I have a working example of using the `PasswordHasher` here: https://github.com/mikebrind/Razor-Pages-In-Action/tree/main/Chapter13/PasswordHasherDemo

If you are migrating an old PHP app to .NET Core, now is the time to improve your security. Anyone who tries to log in using their old PHP password should be told that their password needs resetting, and then you can store the reset one using up-to-date APIs. Store it in a new column, perhaps, so you know whether someone had updated their password or not.

Comment: I need that format sha1(md5($Password)); , I'm aware it's not secure but I need that format, ty